# What's this tree with slightly hairy green leaves with white veins and borders?

Tags: identification, trees

I got a hold of this tree recently (it was in my backyard when I moved in), and want to find out what specific tree it is so I can make sure my care is appropriate. Click to expand pics:

[image: Full tree, with pot]
[image: Close up of bark]
[image: Close up of leaves, side]
[image: Close up of leaves, top]

As the first pic shows, the tree is ~1.7m tall, and in a decent sized pot. It seems to fare well in partial direct sunlight — currently takes ~4h direct sunlight, and seems to like it. I've been watering it about once a week until water drips from the bottom of the pot, which, again, it seems to like.

As the third and fourth pics show, the leaves are slightly hairy/fuzzy, with entire edges, and acuminate apexes ([thanks, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaf#Shape)). They have white (or really light green?) borders and veins. I remember that before the shoots developed into leaves, the buds were way hairier and a really light green too. It has no flowers at all, but I have no idea if it's a flowering tree.

Comment: If there's any more detail I could add to help with the identification, please let me know and I'd be happy to add it to the question! :)